# Is Stack Overflow the correct platform to share what I have got

Tags: discussion

I wanted to migrate my friends' data from phpnuke (forum) to joomla 2.5 kenuna component (forum). And after doing a lot of search I found nothing really useful, so I started to write a migration code. Now I would like to share it so others can use it too.

Can I post it here as a Q&A on Stack Overflow or on any other Stack Exchange site? It's just a lot of code and a lot of description.

Comment: If you just want to *share* code, I would suggest posting it on a site dedicated to sharing code, such as github. Stack Overflow doesn't really the right place for just sharing source code.

Comment: yes its more like a project. but also can I share it here?

Comment: or what if I want to keep some rights for myself about project? like copyright or copy left?

Comment: If you want to maintain distribution rights, SO is *definitely* not the place to post your code. If you *just* want to share code and don't really have a question, the Stack Exchange network is likely not the place for you.

Comment: so u say that I should use github? - the reason I wanted to post it here was that I wanted to ask others to improve its parts like my code can't migrate some little parts of database like emotions in posts.

Comment: I say you should use a platform that's appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: and please put a answer so I can give u +1.

Comment: @imsiso upvotes don't give rep here. git sounds like exactly what you are looking for though. It allows for other people to contribute to improving your code.

Comment: really is this something new? and also I can see my rep in stackoverflow in meta too.?!

Comment: @imsiso No, it isn't really new, but it hasn't always ben that way. In any case, rep doesn't count on Meta (beyond privileges).

Comment: Not a dupe, this isn't about promotion, just sharing.

Comment: @LanceRoberts the purpose of promotion is to share something. I still consider this to be a duplicate. The OP in the linked question himself says "*I want to share my work with everybody (for free).*"

Comment: @Cupcake, I take the other question to be about someone trying to advertise as opposed to just helping others (not that I consider advertising wrong, but the motive is different).

Comment: If you're going to post your code on GitHub or a similar platform, you could put a link in your profile page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now I would like to share it so others can use.

To me, this sounds like you need a *distribution* platform. And the Stack Exchange network is *not* a distribution platform. It's a Q&A network. Using SO for code distribution is like going on Jeopardy to try to sell something. You're looking in the wrong place.

I would suggest taking a look at existing options that are geared towards code distribution (GitHub, BitBucket, and Google Code are some off the top of my head). They would be much more friendly to both you and your users for something like that.

> or what if I want to keep some rights for myself about project? like copyright or copy left?

*If* you find a valid reason to post your project onto SO and are worrying about licensing/copyright, you should probably give the licensing terms of SO a read. At the bottom of each page you see this:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Which are probably a good start. You do give up some rights when posting content to SO, but unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to tell you *exactly* what rights you lose, so I'd recommend looking through those yourself and figuring out whether you are comfortable with those terms.

Answer (score 2):

If you can post a quality question that meets all of the site's guidelines then you're welcome to answer it with a quality answer that also meets all of the sites guidelines.

It doesn't sound like there is a way to turn that problem into a question appropriate for SO though; it appears as if the question is really too broad.  As such, you should probably use some other means of sharing the code publicly, as it doesn't appear to be a fit for SO's model.

Comment: what is SO's model?

Comment: @imsiso Take a look through the help center to see what the site is about for yourself.

Comment: Ok I will, But I thought I know enough about this site after a year. But thank u.

Comment: @imsiso SO's model is that you have questions about real problems that you actually face, and a bunch of folk answer, reasonably succinctly, and people vote the best answers up to the top. Good answers tend to educate folk rather than provide a copy-and-pasteable block of code.